# ASP.NET Core MVC / RAZOR - Styles equivalent of @Section Scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

MVC & Razor allow for scripts to be composed in a specific view. If using a _Layout, a programmer trigger this section to render from inside the `_Layout.cshtml` file by inserting @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

**Example**

**Index.cshtml (view)**

```
...

@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        var input = document.getElementById("search-bar");

        input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById("search-btn").click();
            }
        });

        var searchBtn = document.getElementById("search-btn");
        searchBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            alert("click");

        });

    </script>
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
...

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

I am curious if it is possible to do the same sort of workflow for style sheets. This would enable styles to be composed into the appropriate view making the view a self contained script. This would also prevent the programmer from having to shove every possible css file in the layout and thus loading everything with every route regardless if it is used or not. If this is possible it is unclear to me.

**Proposed Example**

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div>...</div>
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        ...
    </script>
```

}

```
@section Styles {
    <style>
        ...
    </style>
```

}

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SCP_Client</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Solar/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/app.css" />

    **@RenderSection("Styles", Required: false )**

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="header-container">
        <div class="row">
            ... 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="body-container">
        @RenderBody()

    </div>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    **@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)**

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Short answer yes, but I wouldn't recommend this, your css should be in your css files and in fact you should use the bundle code because that will assist with minifying and caching css files. Same with your js files.

Comment: You can make any number of sections that you want.

Comment: I suppose i could accomplish my goal by building more view specific bundles. Including them in a view / view group specific layout and then use that layout in my view. May be over engineering this, but I think there is value in only loading scripts / styles relevant to the view where possible in addition to minifying / caching benefits.

Comment: I wouldn't say so, maybe there are some things that are quite heavy e.g a html editor - fckeditor. But most other stuff is pretty small, so loading jquery and bootstrap together as well as any other plugins is pretty good as your going to use them on most pages. 
But you can have a scripts segment with a bundle in there. So that is a way to go.

Comment: Also if you create loads of bundles then you loose time with the actual request/download - so it makes little sense.

Comment: Makes since. Thanks for the input. I just recently looked into vuejs which has the notion of single file views and scoped styling. That is what got me going down this rabbit hole.

Comment: No worries, I just remember ages ago when I was in a team and there was a main.css page but then people made there own inline styles and then we had to rationalise it all. Also a current project which I've inherited has crazy inline styles and yeah it's a mess. Inline styles suck